# $injector:modulerr using angular-strap?

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I am trying to get going with angular-strap directives, but encountering a module initialization error with the simplest setup. I have double checked a zillion times but can't see exactly what I might be missing.

Here is a plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/H1VrF63GeSQWLXHDVIW7

The error I get is:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module mgcrea.ngStrap due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'mgcrea.ngStrap' is not available! You either misspe...  <omitted>...1)
```

I read [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066299/injectormodulerr-when-i-use-angular-strap), but it didn't answer my question as I am not using ngSanitize or routes. This is as simple as it gets.

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem lays in the old version of the angular-strap. You should include files specified at https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap#quick-start

Comment: Yea, thanks. Including *all* the scripts in the quick start works fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your plunk needs angular-animate, which angular-strap [depends on](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap).

http://plnkr.co/hsqT3FLEjXwdnXrxn4hx

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Actually silly developer (though thanks! ;-) ) of android strap not to write it on his gitup imho.

Comment: I wish they would have included that in the list of dependent script files: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap