# Angular Strap module won't inject into my application

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I'm trying to get Angular Strap working.

I can have a controller where data binding works. Then when I add ['mgcrea.ngStrap'], the data binding breaks. It literally just says {{example-value}} instead of the value.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['mgcrea.ngStrap']);
```

Can someone please give the example javascript code for Angular Strap? Maybe we can use the datepicker as an example?

I think part of the problem might be loading it with the MEAN stack. If I put ng-controller="MainCtrl" in the < body > of my default layout.html, the views/header won't load. So basically nothing on the page loads. Here's the data-ng-include code from the views/layouts/default.html

```
    <div class="navbar" data-ng-include="'views/header.html'" data-role="navigation"></div>
```

- the angular strap javascript files are included at the bottom of the html page
- The < body > won't let me do ng-controller="MainCtrl"
- angular.module('MyApp').controller E T C works for data binding but angular strap still isn't there. So the controller is set up correctly
- angular.module('MyApp', ['mgcrea.ngStrap']).controller E T C breaks the data binding that once worked and angular strap isn't there

Comment: which error you got at console?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem:

http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=esqbApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.15%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dmgcrea.ngStrap%26p1%3DErro

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22341614/618906) I found elsewhere is that angular-strap depends on angular-animate, so be sure to include it.