# trying to get angularstrap working but no luck

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-strap

I am trying to get angularstrap working but have not had any luck yet. here is my angular code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Learning AngularJS</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/angular.strap/2.0.0/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/angular.strap/2.0.0/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='content' ng-app='MyTutorialApp' ng-controller='MainController'>
{{understand}}
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('MyTutorialApp',['mgcrea.ngStrap']);
    app.controller("MainController", function($scope){
        $scope.understand = "I now understand how the scope works!";
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get this error

```
Uncaught object ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js:33
```

when I take   mgcrea.ngStrap out from

```
var app = angular.module('MyTutorialApp',['mgcrea.ngStrap']);
```

then it works. Any help will be appreciated!

[image: Here is a snapshot of angular debugger for dependencies]

Comment: possible duplicate of [$injector:modulerr using angular-strap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334332/injectormodulerr-using-angular-strap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[angularstrap](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap) depends on angular animate..

include this
 `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular-animate.min.js"></script>` 
It is already answered here : [$injector:modulerr using angular-strap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334332/injectormodulerr-using-angular-strap/22341614#22341614)

> AngularStrap is lighter and faster than ever as it does leverage the
>   power of ngAnimate from AngularJS 1.2+!

https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/651

Comment: thank you that worked. However can you please tell me how did you figure it was missing. I guess I am trying to find out a way to tell if this kind of thing happens in future. thanks

Comment: AngularStrap is lighter and faster than ever as it does leverage the power of ngAnimate from AngularJS 1.2+!...according to the docs..http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/

Comment: And check out this discussion...https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/651