# $injector:modulerr error on using angular-strap

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-strap

I am using [angular-strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/).

I have gone through following links:

- [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066299/injectormodulerr-when-i-use-angular-strap)
- [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066299/injectormodulerr-when-i-use-angular-strap)

But I get 
`Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=test&p1=Error%3A%2…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.16%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A431)` 
error on running following code.

```
<html ng-app="test">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/angular.strap/2.0.0/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/angular.strap/2.0.0/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('test', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'mgcrea.ngStrap']);
</script>
</html>
```

What is the matter with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You've added `ngAnimate` as a dependency but did not reference `angular-animate.js` file.

Add this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

Or lose the 'ngAnimate' in:

```
angular.module('test', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'mgcrea.ngStrap']);
```